# Search for a string and return the word behind it into an array

Tags: php, string

I have a long string and I want to retrieve all words preceding a `.png`

For example I have:

```
blablabla /name01.png blablabla /name_may_have_different_sizes02.png blablabla
```

And I want to get an array with `name01.png` and `name_may_have_different_sizes02.png`

Some images have a path like /folder1/folder2/image.png I also wanted to take only the file name and not the entire path.

Comment: Look into `preg_match_all()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
preg_match_all('#/(([^/ ]*)\.png)#', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]); // with extension
print_r($matches[2]); // without extension
```

prints:

```
Array ( [0] => name01.png [1] => name_may_have_different_sizes02.png )
Array ( [0] => name01 [1] => name_may_have_different_sizes02 )
```

Explanation:

`#/(([^/ ]*)\.png)#` is a pattern searching for string starting with `/` followed by any character(s) - except of whitespace and `/`. At the end have to be `.png`

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off not using regex, as others are suggesting.

```
$input = "blablabla /name01.png ......";
$parts = explode(" ",$input);
$files = array_filter($parts,function($word) {return substr($word,-4) == ".png";});
```

Done!

Answer (score -1):

You should use regexp and in PHP **preg_match_all** function (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)

> And regexp pattern: **#/(.*?).png#**

It works as you need, check in Online RegEx Tester:
[Check your example here](http://regexpr.com/)